# My game keeps crashing when I try to run the build but not in the Unity Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, build, crash

Whenever I try to run my game in Unity Editor, it works normally; but i wanted to test if everything is working properly in the builds and it kept crashing the game whenever I tried too run it.
I have attached the contents of the error.log file.

i am making this game for a game jam and need to resolve this issue

error.log FILE

```
0x00007FFC7B6A3B86 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_RegisteredNetwork_BufferSlice_Empty
0x00007FFC7BD2BE45 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7C4900C6 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Memory_Free
0x00007FFC7C1BB525 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Memory_Free
0x00007FFC7C1BA104 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Memory_Free
0x00007FFC7C1BEC21 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Memory_Free
0x00007FFC7C1DEA8E (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Memory_Free
0x00007FFC7C1DE88D (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Memory_Free
0x00007FFC7BCCDC47 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCCDCE7 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCD1BA3 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BAB981E (UnityPlayer) AbortShim::operator=
0x00007FFC7BAB865A (UnityPlayer) AbortShim::operator=
0x00007FFC7BABC636 (UnityPlayer) AbortShim::operator=
0x00007FFC7BABD8EB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Attempt to access invalid address.' (Address: 00007FF70CF311F2)
0x00007FF70CF311F2 (SCREAM Jam 2020) (function-name not available)
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

Stacks for Running Threads:

Call Stack for Thread 9296:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 32840:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 40816:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 32420:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC8D8C5E8F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_conc_hashtable_remove
0x00007FFC8D9B434D (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_gc_reference_queue_new
0x00007FFC8D9B3125 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_callspec_parse
0x00007FFC8D976398 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_threads_set_shutting_down
0x00007FFC8D976126 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_threads_set_shutting_down
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 35144:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 40876:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 39024:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 42204:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 21388:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 1536:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 37832:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 41516:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 38468:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 25476:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 40332:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 22748:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 19992:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 39892:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 41088:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 12988:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 25760:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 39036:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 31864:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 41772:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 41728:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 39128:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 29932:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCAAC3A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCABF50 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 34604:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BD9424A (UnityPlayer) baselib::Thread::YieldExecution
0x00007FFC7BCC674C (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43212:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BBB3A4E (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 41532:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 40140:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C65D3DA (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7C65D32E (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7C5EA6C6 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7CAAD910 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 35884:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C63F965 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7C5E898A (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7C5EA691 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7CAAD910 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 32576:
0x00007FFD0C21C744 (ntdll) NtDelayExecution
0x00007FFD095DFC21 (KERNELBASE) SleepEx
0x00007FFC7C5E8B3A (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7C5EA6F4 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFC7CAAD910 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_Timer_WaitForAtLeast
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43740:
0x00007FFD0C21C144 (ntdll) NtWaitForSingleObject
0x00007FFD095D1E93 (KERNELBASE) WaitForSingleObjectEx
0x00007FFC7C53F592 (UnityPlayer) Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire
0x00007FFC7BCF12FA (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BCF1479 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFC7BD93328 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43816:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 36056:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 36460:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43668:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43672:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43664:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 14140:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 31072:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43392:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 36628:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43868:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 40916:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43084:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 40992:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43808:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43544:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 34160:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 39000:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 28400:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 32292:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 37160:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43184:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43720:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 33700:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 34736:
0x00007FFD0C21CC14 (ntdll) NtWaitForMultipleObjects
0x00007FFD095E2AE7 (KERNELBASE) WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
0x00007FFCC65671F3 (msmpeg2vdec) DllGetClassObject
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 5896:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43844:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


Call Stack for Thread 43592:
0x00007FFD0C21FA54 (ntdll) NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
0x00007FFD0C1B3FE0 (ntdll) RtlInitializeResource
0x00007FFD0A6B7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD0C1ECEA1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: UPDATE>> I tried to build an APK to see if that works, and it did. The problem lies with the Windows Standalone build, I just don't know where...

Comment: This looks quite unresolvable without knowing anything else about your project .. here we see only some machine code addresses and the error message but how should we reproduce any of it here?

Comment: basically, I am making a 3D game where most of the 3d assets are being imported from .fbx or .blend files and I have tried to not change project settings except for physics. idk why it is not running properly on PC but running on mobile

Comment: Are all of your scenes in the build settings?

Comment: yes. all the scenes are in the build settings